# hibernate ddl-auto don't work with MySql but it worked with H2

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have finished my spring boot application, and now I'm trying to deploy it with docker-compose. While developing I have used H2 in-memory DB and all was fine. Now I'm trying to switch data source to MySql and hibernate isn't creating any tables in MySql Database. Then my Spring boot app trying to do some actions and can't find any tables (because it wasn't created on start).
I have exceptions like

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'db.test_run' doesn't exist
```

I tried to switch ddl-auto to create-drop or update and had the same result. My config is:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db
    username: user
    password: password
    driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    jpa:
      database: mysql
      database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
      show-sql: true
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: create
  jackson:
    serialization:
      write-dates-as-timestamps: false
```

Db is working and I can connect to it via Idea browser and I can create tables with "user" user. My MySql server config in docker-compose:

```
 db:
    image: mysql/mysql-server
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db'
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    expose:
      - 3306
```

I guess my application classes is fine because it works with h2 DB and tables still creating with h2. 
I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.6 and latest docker image MySql 8.0.20

Comment: Do you use Spring Data Jpa? Because ddl-auto is Data JPA specific property. In other cases, you have to use hbm2ddl.auto property. Also, auto ddl only creates tables, make sure thats the shema was created (it should done by docker prop anyway) and all the necessary privilages was granted to the user you are using to the app.

Comment: try using `spring.jpa.generate-ddl = true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it, section "jpa" needs to be under "spring" section, not under "datasource" section. And it worked with h2 because spring data using ddl-auto: create-drop by default for embedded databases.